# Cauchy's integral theorem proof from Green's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, analytic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

I am studying Cauchy's integral theorem from shaum's outline,the theorem states that

> Let $f(z)$ be analytic in a region $R$ and on its boundary $C$. Then $$\oint_{C}f(z)dz=0$$

After the statement of this theorem,it is written there:

> This fundamental theorem, often called Cauchy’s integral theorem or simply Cauchy’s theorem, is valid for both simply and multiple-connected regions. It was first proved by use of Green’s theorem with the added restriction that $f'(z)$ be continuous in $R$. However, Goursat gave a proof which removed this restriction. For this reason, the theorem is sometimes called the Cauchy –Goursat theorem when one desires to emphasize the removal of this restriction.

> **My Question**:If a function is analytic in a region then we know that all its derivatives are analytic in that region and hence they are continuous,then why this added restriction of continuity was required while proving the theorem with the help of *Green's theorem*?Whether this fact was not known at that time(the fact that if a function is analytic then it is smooth) and Goursat used it in his proof?

Comment: "If a function is analytic in a region then we know that all its derivatives are analytic". The usual proofs of this **uses** results such as Cauchy's theorem and Cauchy's integral formula. Do you have an alternative proof that doesn't.

Comment: I studied the definition of analytic function as follows:"A function f is said to be analytic at a point if there is neighborhood of that point on which f converges to a power series(more precisely f converges to its Taylor series in a disk around that point)" and hence by default it is smooth

Comment: According to Ahlfors: "The class of analytic functions is formed by
the complex functions of a complex variable which possess a derivative
wherever the function is defined." Proving such functions are locally power series is a non-trivial undertaking.

Comment: Ok I got it,so my claim is vice versa of what I uses if I take definition according to ahlfors